# Problem with one implication in equivalence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

### The problem

I want to check truthfulness about equivalence :

$$E(|X_n-X|) \rightarrow 0  \Leftrightarrow X_n \rightarrow X\;in\;probability.$$

### What I've Done

"$\Rightarrow$"
Using Chebyshev's inequality i get :

$P(|X_n-X|\ge \varepsilon) \le \frac{E(|X_n-X|)}{\varepsilon}\rightarrow0 \Rightarrow X_n\rightarrow X$ in probability.

"$\Leftarrow$"

A'im not sure about this implication, my intuition tell's me that it's truth but i cant figure out any prove of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convergence on the left is called $L^1$-convergence. You can find something more about convergence of random variables on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables).

$L^1$-convergence implies convergence in probability, but the other implication is false: consider $X_n = 2^{n} \mathbb{1}_{[1/2^{n+1},1/2^{n}]}$ and $X = 0$ on the space of probability $([0,1],\mu)$. Then:

$$P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) = P(X_n > \epsilon) = P(2^{n} \mathbb{1}_{[1/2^{n+1},1/2^{n}]} > \epsilon) = \mu([1/2^{n+1},1/2^{n}]) \rightarrow_{n \rightarrow \infty} 0$$

so $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability, but $E(|X_n - X|) = E(X_n) = 1/2$, so there isn't $L^1$-convergence.